# While loop executing 1 more time than expected

Tags: variables, makefile, while-loop

While loop inside Make object executes 1 more time than expected.

I am using while loop in my make object to check some files. I need to run it 3 times but it runs 4 times with the first loop without the while index set.

```
check_diag_results:
    @echo "Checking Diagnostic Test Results ..."
    @number = 1; \
    while [[ $$number -le 3 ]]; do \
        if grep -q 'Test PASSED' "$(RESULTS)/diagnostics_rtl_tc$$number.txt"; then \
            echo "Testcase $$number Passed"; \
        else \
            echo "Testcase $$number Failed"; \
        fi; \
    (( number = $$number + 1 )); \
    done
    @echo "... Done"
```

Here is the result:

```
Checking Diagnostic Test Results ...
/usr/bin/sh: number: command not found
grep: ./results/diagnostics_rtl_tc.txt: No such file or directory
Testcase  Failed
Testcase 1 Passed
Testcase 2 Passed
Testcase 3 Failed
... Done
```

As you can see, the first time, number is not defined even though it is set above the while.

Comment: Some ideas: try `SHELL = bash` in the Makefile, try using a `for` loop, try `.ONESHELL` instead of backslash escapes, ...

Comment: Change `@number = 1; \` to `@number=1; \`, and I notice that this isn't the first time you've posted about an error caused by stray whitespace in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 'number' initialiser to one without '@' character like so:

before: `@number = 1; \`

after: `number = 1; \`

Comment: This is not relevant: the `@` is part of the makefile and is not passed to the shell.